# How do I display a prompt when the cursor enters an overlay in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing a minor mode which dispenses writing advice. I am using overlays to highlight mistakes. When the point enters the overlay, I want to display more detail (with `message` for now, but maybe in a separate buffer.)

`help-echo` is *almost* what I want, but I use Gnu Emacs in the terminal, and `help-echo` is for the mouse pointer, not the point.

`point-entered` is also *almost* what I want, but `point-entered` doesn't have any effect in overlays, only text properties.

Overlays looked appealing in the first place because it is easy to obliterate them when I reparse the buffer (I'm cribbing from what `re-builder` does here.) Should I continue using overlays but use point motion hooks to find the overlays, extract the prompts, and display them? Should I be using text properties instead of overlays?

Comment: I am not an expert, but it seems like overlays are meant to be more "write-only", for changing presentation rather than changing behavior. It looks like you can do it with overlays if you use point motion hooks and functions like `overlays-at`, but text properties may be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to try `cursor-sensor-mode` (which is new in Emacs-25) which lets you place actions on the `cursor-sensor-functions` text properties (including via overlays).

It is intended to replace the `point-entered` property and reacts to movements of the cursor rather than to movements of `point` (the two are closely related, yet different: a given command can move point *many* times internally, but the cursor will only be moved once, at the end when the display is updated).

Answer (score 0):

For some ideas, check out [auto-complete mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete).

It pops up a menu at point that people can scroll through.  This may not be exactly what you want - sounds like you don't want a menu - but looking into the code might be interesting.

[image]

Also see the tooltip-show method, part of tooltip.el.

```
tooltip-show is a compiled Lisp function in `tooltip.el'.

(tooltip-show TEXT &optional USE-ECHO-AREA)

Show a tooltip window displaying TEXT.

Text larger than `x-max-tooltip-size' is clipped.

If the alist in `tooltip-frame-parameters' includes `left' and `top'
parameters, they determine the x and y position where the tooltip
is displayed.  Otherwise, the tooltip pops at offsets specified by
`tooltip-x-offset' and `tooltip-y-offset' from the current mouse
position.

Optional second arg USE-ECHO-AREA non-nil means to show tooltip
in echo area.
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not a good design to react on mouse movements, as the mouse will most probably pass by your areas for many reasons.

I would advice you to implement this on, for example, the right menu button.

When it comes to overlays vs. text properties -- one difference is that text properties are retained when doing `buffer-substring`, which is probably not what you want. Another is that text properties are shared between inherited buffers (even though this is a seldom used feature).

Comment: He's not trying to react to mouse movements; he wants to react to point.

Comment: My mistake. However, the same argument can be made for point movement.

Comment: Yes—I want to react to point movement, not mouse movement. I‘m not particularly worried about the point traversing a region for other reasons—the echoed text is non-modal and peripheral. But I‘m curious what UI you would think is better for this. Something like running ispell is *way* too heavy-weight for me; I want it to give continuous subtle feedback.